# Show data on targeted widget in kivy-python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am new for Kivy-pyhton. I'm using python3 for using kivy-tool

I've developed a small application in kivy-tool

I am making an application to take data from user, save in a file, then on click of any button, I want to show data on widget

code for the application is:-

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import os
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout


Builder.load_string('''
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Add New Employee'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'add_staff'
        Button:
            text: 'View Employee Profile'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'read_staff'
        Button:
            text: 'Salary report'


<read_New_staff>:
    # nam: str(name_input)
    # job: job_input
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            id: label
            font_size: 24
            bold: True
            height: root.height * .9
            size_hint_y: None
            # text: "file Content show here....."
            text_size: self.width, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            valign: 'middle'
            halign: 'center'

        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: 'Show Data'
            on_press: app.show()

<Lay>:
    cols: 1
    label: label
    padding: 20
    Label:
        height: root.height * .1
        size_hint_y: None
        text: 'Read what is below'
        font_size: 24
        bold: True
    ScrollView:
        height: root.height * .85
        size_hint_y: None
        Label:
            id: label
            font_size: 24
            bold: True
            height: root.height * .9
            size_hint_y: None
            text: 'we will rock you'
            text_size: self.width, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            # valign: 'middle'
            # halign: 'center'


<Add_new_staff>:
    # nam: str(name_input)
    # job: job_input
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: 'Product Name'
        TextInput:
            id: name_input
        Label:
            text: 'Price'
        TextInput:
            id: price_input
        Label:
            text: 'Priority'
        TextInput:
            id: priority_input
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: 'Save'
            on_press: app.save(name_input.text, price_input.text,priority_input.text)
''')


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Add_new_staff(Screen):
    pass

class read_New_staff(Screen):
    pass

class Lay(GridLayout):
    label = ObjectProperty()

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(Add_new_staff(name='add_staff'))
sm.add_widget(read_New_staff(name='read_staff'))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        l = Lay()
        fob = open('/home/vyclean14/Desktop/Rohit_kivy/test.txt','r')
        content = fob.read()
        fob.close()
        l.label.text = content
        self.hello = Button(text = "hello")
        self.hello.bind(on_press = self.show)       
        return sm  #l

    def save(self, name,price,priority):
        fob = open('/home/vyclean14/Desktop/Rohit_kivy/test.txt','a')
        fob.write("Product Name:- " + name + "\n")
        fob.write("Price:- " + price + "\n")
        fob.write("Priority:- " + priority + "\n")
        fob.write("--------------------\n")
        fob.close()    

    def show(self, *args):
        l = Lay()
        fob = open('/home/vyclean14/Desktop/Rohit_kivy/test.txt','r')
        content = fob.read()
        fob.close()
        # l.label.text = content
        print(content)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
    # NewApp().run()
```

Main View:

[image]

As user click on Add employee, His entered data added in `.txt` file

As I click on 'View Employee Detail' Show Data opens.

[image]

On Click of show data I want to show data in 1st quadrant

How can I achive this

Thank You